# How to find unique occurance of a value based an another value using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataset.

---

```
Student_code   Subject
___________    _______
123            Maths
123            Chemistry
124            Maths
125            Chemistry
126            Physics
126            Maths
127            Physics
127            Chemistry
```

I would like to find number of students who have just enrolled for one course. In this example, given "Maths", i should get 1 as answer as student id 124 enrolled just for Maths.

Comment: wouldn't student `125` also come up because of chemistry?

Comment: Thats right. Given Chemistry, i should get just 125.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to return students who only took one class, You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df.groupby('Student_code', as_index=False).filter(lambda x: x['Subject'].count() ==1 )

  Student_code    Subject
3          124      Maths
4          125  Chemistry
```

Comment: Thanks. It works

Comment: @RavindraPrasad, great! if this answered your question, please mark as "accepted" and/or upvote if this solved your problem. by marking accepted it lets the Data Science Network see that this question was answered